# Gtkmm Build Error

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

OS: Debian 9.1

Compiler: gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18)

GTK+ Version: 3.22.11-1

Gtkmm Version: 3.22.0-1

Hello all, I've been dealing with a pesky issue with Gtkmm 3.22.0-1 build the simple application given on the [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en). I'm building the project using CMake, and I get the following error:

```
error: 'Gtk::Application' has not been declared
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
(recipe for target failed, etc...)
```

This error comes as a result of the standard "simplest program" for Gtkmm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto app =
        Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
        "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

    Gtk::Window win;
    win.set_default_size(200, 200);

    return app->run(win);
}
```

From research I can say that this error was common near the release of Gtkmm 3 as Gtk::Application was not implemented until Gtkmm 3.4 (around 2012). The example given above is for Gtkmm 3 from the GNOME documentation site (link above).

I have installed Gtkmm-3-dev, pkg-config returns all the right flags and directories, and the CMakeLists.txt includes the following:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRE)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3)
link_directories( ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
...
target_link_libraries(proj ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} )
```

Where 'proj' is the name of my project. I'm running Debian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch). The output of pkg-config gtkmm-3 --cflags:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0/unix-print -I/usr/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/usr/include/giomm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/giomm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pangomm-1.4/include -I/usr/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibmm-2.4/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cairomm-1.0/include -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sigc++-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

I cannot find any recent posts related to this problem, and my next option is to sift through the Gtkmm API docs in search of an answer. I found that there is a Gio::Application that might work in a similar way, but I have not explored this fully. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Sam

Comment: I don't know how CMake works, but I just managed it to run this code on Debian 9.1 with gtkmm.  Have you tried to run it directly without using CMake? `g++ main.cc $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtkmm-3.0)`

Comment: Interesting, maybe I need to rerun cmake and make sure it's using the right version of Gtkmm. Ill try it next time Im at my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the issue was with CMake not finding Gtkmm-3 because the package is titled "gtkmm-3.0". So this line in CMakeLists.txt:

```
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3)
```

Is supposed to be:

```
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)
```

Thanks to JohnKoch for helping resolve this issue.

Comment: I think your CMake definition is problematic. The make-file process should fail immediately when it could not find `gtkmm-3`(correct mod should be `gtkmm-3.0`). Improve your CMake file and set module as required by project.

Comment: As @JohnKoch said, you should use `pkg_check_modules(GTKMM REQUIRED gtkmm-3.0)`. The `REQUIRED` argument makes sure configuration fails il the module is not found.